# Inserting new object with many to many relationship in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I have a json object of `Movies` that I'm passing to my controller.

```
{data : [{
    Id: 12345,
    Title: 'Movie1',
    Year: 2010,
    Character: [{
        Name: 'Character1',
        Person: { Id: 1, Name: 'Person1' }
    },{
        Name: 'Character2',
        Person: { Id: 2, Name: 'Person2' }
    }]
}]}
```

The model binding is working fine but I'm having an issue inserting each `Movie` into the database via Entity Framework 5. I'm getting a primary key violation when each `Person` for a movie is being inserted.

I understand why this is happening. Some people already exist in the database when adding a new `Movie` so the violation occurs. The Id for each person is not auto generated. I'm using the Id that I receive from the api I get the information from.

A `Movie` has a many-to-many relationship with `Person`, with `Character` being the bridge between the two.

```
public class Movie {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int? Year { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Character> Characters { get; set; } 

    public Movie() {
        Characters = new HashSet<Character>();
    }
}

public class Character {
    public string Name { get; set; }    
    public virtual Movie Movie { get; set; }    
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}

public class Person {
    public int Id { get;set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Character> Characters { get; set; }

    public Person() {
        Characters = new HashSet<Character>();
    }
}
```

My question is... I know I can loop through each `Person` object and `Attach()` if it exists or `Add()` if it doesn't. **Can Entity Framework automatically handle inserting a new `Person` and ignore it if it already exists? If not, what is the best practice for this type of problem?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is unnecessary to Attach the Person objects if they already exist.

What I would do is loop through the API Person objects and compare with the EF DbContext.

```
var dbPerson = MyMovieContext.Persons.Where(x => x.ID == myPersonID).SingleOrDefault();
```

If you don't find a match, then Add.  If you do find a match, then replace the reference on Character with the Entity from the DbContext.

Comment: This works for almost every scenario. There are some movies where a person can play more than one role. If they don't exist in the database then I'm still getting a primary key violation because as it's adding each person from a movie it inserts person1 from character1 then tries to insert person1 from character2, but since person1 now exists in the db it throws an exception. Any thoughts?

Comment: After you insert person1 as you process character1, it should be fetching person1 from the context when you are processing character2.  perhaps you are checking if a person exists at the wrong point in your code?

Comment: But person1 won't exist in the database until the changes have committed (`SaveChanges()`).

Comment: @bflemi3 yes but it exists on the context once you add it, and will be returned when you do the `Where`.  As long as you are querying the same instance of MyMovieContext that you had previously added Person1 to it will be found.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the DbContext API you can use the [`AddOrUpdate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846520%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) extension method. Let's assume you've got a list or persons, then you can do:

```
context.Persons.AddOrUpdate(persons.ToArray());
```

You would probably do this for each model item (`persons` are the persons of the item) and then create `Character` objects with `Person` and `Movie` objects attached.

Note that `AddOrUpdate` only adds or updates in the context. Only `SaveChanges` commits to the database.